# Very big numbers make bcpowmod overflow

Tags: php

I need to raise 8 to the power of 17 in PHP. I have checked this to be 2251799813685248 on my PC's calculator, but both the `pow()` and `bcpowmod()` functions seem to overflow; `pow()` goes into scientific notation, and echoing the results from `bcpowmod()`, even with a high third parameter gives me a blank screen. Is there any other way I could perform this calculation?

Comment: Just use `bcpow()`, `bcpowmod()` will compute `x^y % z`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try with [`gmp_pow`](http://php.net/gmp_pow)

```
gmp_pow("8", 17);
```

With [`h2ooooooo`](https://stackoverflow.com/users/247893/h2ooooooo) suggestion - to get result use:

```
gmp_strval(gmp_pow("8", 17));
```

Also [`bcpow`](http://php.net/bcpow) works well for me

```
bcpow("8", "17")
```

Comment: It should be added that you *might* have to use [`gmp_strval`](http://dk1.php.net/manual/en/function.gmp-strval.php) to get the result from `gmp`; `gmp_strval(gmp_pow("8", 17));`

Comment: "Fatal error: Call to undefined function gmp_pow()" is what I get for `gmp_pow()`. `bcpow()` gives me 2.2517998136852E+15; is there a way to change this, and make it give me the actual number?

Comment: Maybe you can install `gmp` module ? http://pl1.php.net/manual/en/gmp.installation.php

Answer (score 1):

Use `pow()`. The "scientific notation" you are talking about is just a notation and you can format it later.

```
echo number_format(pow(8,17), 0, '', '');
```

http://php.net/number-format

Beside this I couldn't reproduce the "scientific-notation"-behaviour for the given values

http://codepad.viper-7.com/AwM3CS (Uses bigger values to enforce the scientific notation)